# Element of an array as a reference to another array?

Tags: java

I am trying to have a 2D Array that is 16 rows by 11 columns where row 0, column 3 is a reference to another array that is a single dimension array. How do i go about doing this? I already have both arrays where the single dimension array is a char array(although i could make it a string array if i wanted) and the 2D array is a string array. The rest of the 2D Array is filled with plain strings for each elements with the exception of row 0, column 3 which i want it to be the single dimension array.

Comment: Why does my code matter? The question is pretty specific... do you want me to post two arrays filled? ...

Comment: What do you wish to accomplish with this?  Placing an array in the middle of a 2D matrix of other data is pretty wonky.  Maybe if we understood your problem space a bit better, we could guide you to a more ideal (and easier to code) solution.

Comment: Tell us what your program is try to deal with, because your design sound very _mysterious_ so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object[] arrayToReference = ...;
Object[][] arrayWithReference =  new Object[] { ..., arrayToReference, ...};
```

This should work; just reference the array and it should change as the original changes

Here's an example code snippet:

```
    Object[] array = new Object[] { "Test!" };
    Object[][] arrayArray = new Object[][] { array };
    System.out.println("Before: " + arrayArray[0][0]);
    array[0] = "Test2!";
    System.out.println("After: " + arrayArray[0][0]);
```

which has the following output:

```
Before: Test!
After: Test2!
```

Answer (score 0):

That just sounds like your approach to the problem is wrong. Maybe you should rethink your data structure. Normally, an array is typed. You can't really decide to insert a different type in one cell.

If you really can't change the data structure, try inserting a single dimension array of strings in each cell with only 1 entry in them, which is the string that goes there normally, except for row 0, column 3, which already is an array.

Comment: what do you mean by typed? as in data type?

Comment: Yes, data type. If you have a string[], you can't add another string[] to it, only a string.

Comment: 2D arrays are defined of arrays of arrays. In this way, a 2D array of a type can contain a 1D array of the same type.

Comment: Agreed, but he's trying to add a 1D array to a 1D array.

Comment: no, i want to add a 1D array to a 2D array(one of it's element) - row 0, column 3. I want my program to go through this 2D array and see if each element matches with the user's input. When my program checks this specific element(row 0, column 3) of the 2D array, I want it to go through the 1D array's elements to check if it matches the user's input. Basically I want that specific element of the 2D array to be a reference to my 1D array so that it checks the 1D array's elements. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking a bit of an overkill solution, but should work for this with some refining. If it is possible for you.

Can you make two classes that implement the same interface? First one will be the type of the 2D array, and the other one would be class with the 1D array.

Since they implement a common interface, you can make a 2D array with that interface. That kind of 2D array can accept any kind of the two objects on any place in it.